# Install git python library through python regardless of OS

Tags: python

I have developed a tool that my team can use after running the `setup.py` script. The tool requires this library: https://github.com/c2nes/javalang

How can I make my python setup script install this library on their computer regardless of what OS they are on. They can't run my tool without that library (Some people are on windows, mac, and linux.)

Comment: Why not include it as a requirement (`install_requires`) in your `setup.py`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is my first time doing this, I didn't even know about the `requirements.txt` file for specifying requirements and then feeding it into pip install. I didn't know you could do that - that's cool. But what if they don't have pip?

Comment: ...then they can install `pip`? It comes with most versions of Python (3.4 onwards), or you can run `get-pip.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pip` can install projects on Github as a dependency too!](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git)

All you need to do is, in your `requirements.txt`, add a line like following:

```
..
git+https://github.com/c2nes/javalang.git
```

then install the dependency using:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

What you are looking for exists on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javalang). Instead of `git+https://..` line above, just say: `javalang`. Oh and BTW, unless *they* are running old versions of Python,  they should already have `pip` installed. If they don't use your operating systems package manager or `get-pip.py` as you said.

Comment: What if they don't have pip? Is that going to be a problem.

Comment: It's on PyPI, no need to hit GitHub: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javalang

Comment: So you're saying I can just say `python get-pip.py` if they don't have pip and then just run `pip install javalang`? How can I determine whether or not it's necessary to run the first command. I.e., maybe they already have pip.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I assumed it didn't exist on pypi. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!